# Entity Framework Core and One-to-One Relation: Duplicate entry

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

There's One-to-One relationship:

```
builder.Entity<Models.Card>()
    .HasOne<Models.Owner>()
    .WithOne(c => c.Card)
    .HasForeignKey<Models.Owner>("OwnerId");
```

At this moment
    `OwnerId = 1 has Card.Id = 333`
and
    `OwnerId = 2 has Card.Id = 444`

If try to change CardId for `OwnerId = 1` to `CardId = 444` I'll get an error like `Duplicate entry ... for key ...`, because OwnerId = 2 already has the same Card (Card.Id = 444).

What is the best way to prevent this behavior: to remove Card.Id = 444 from OwnerId = 2 and change CardId to requested for Owner 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes; 1:1 is enforced via unique FK on one side, so the `Owner.CardId` property for `OwnerId = 2` must first be changed to a different value (or that `Owner` record deleted).

Unless both sides of the relationship are optional (i.e. an `Owner` doesn't have to have a `Card` and a `Card` doesn't have to have an `Owner`), a shared primary key should be used (the optional side of the 1:? relationship's PK should also be a FK to the requried side's PK)

Answer (score 0):

First set the `CardId` for `OwnerId` to null (if this can be made as `null`), but again it will give you duplicate key if any other row has `null` value. So you have to delete the row for this `ownerId`and then update the required row.